# what does the `=` mean in generic parameter definition?

Tags: typescript

Both `e` and `f` are correct, but why the `f` function works? I've seen the codes like `DP extends Partial<P> = Partial<P>` existing, but I want to know why the `=` is there.

```
interface I {
    name: string
}

type IOpt = Partial<I>

function e<E extends IOpt>(p: E) {
    p.name = 'p'
}
function f<E extends IOpt=IOpt>(p: E) {
    p.name = 'p'
}
```

---

updated: why below code not work?

```
function f<E=IOpt>(p: E) {
    p.name = 'p'
    ~Property 'name' does not exist on type 'E'.
}
```

Comment: It's a default value of a type parameter. So `E` equals `IOpt` if not provided.

Comment: Thank you, and now I have another question: why this code below does not work?
```
function f<E=IOpt>(p: E) {
    p.name = 'p'
}
```

Comment: What does "does not work" exactly mean?

Comment: function f<E=IOpt>(p: E) {
    p.name = 'p'
    ~Property 'name' does not exist on type 'E'.
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function f<E=IOpt>(p: E) {
    p.name = 'p'
}
```

from your example does not type check because nothing guarantees generic type `E` has the `name` property.

Eg: `f(42)` - this is a valid call, yet `p` is a `number`.

Comment: nothing guarantees generic type E has the name property ======>   doesn't `<E=IOpt>` define E to be IOpt ?

Comment: @jiajianrong nope, `IOpt` is a default value if not provided, but in this case it was inferred to be a `number`. Do you really need it to be generic? Are you sure `function f(p: IOpt) {` won't fit your needs?

Comment: `E=IOpt` is what I mock up , it's not a real case. Sorry for that.